# Improving Linear regression ,L1 and L2 regularization of rainfall data in python

Tags: python, linear-regression, lasso-regression

I am using a linear regression model to predict rainfall.

```
 dfx = df1[['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL',
           'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']]
    dfy=df1['ANNUAL']
    
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dfx, dfy, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
```

x is rainfall in 12 months and y is the annual rainfall which is the sum of 12 months.

When I run a linear regression with the below code.

```
#create a linear regression model
regressor = LinearRegression() 

# fitting the model
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

#predicting response 
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
testScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test,y_pred))
print('testScore: %.2f RMSE' % (testScore))
print('R2 SCORE:', r2_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

I got testScore: 0.11 RMSE and R2 SCORE: 0.9999999338525851 .

So to get a better result I did L1 and L2 regularization with code.

```
  ##create a Ridge model
    rdf = Ridge(alpha = .5)
    
    ## create Lasso model
    lrf = Lasso(alpha = .5)
```

For ridge and Lasso I got the same R2 as linear regression which is 0.99.
For ridge i gor RMSE of 0.11 and 0.13 for Lasso.

Again  to improve the model ,I have added hyperparameter tuning to Ridge and Lasso

For Ridge:

```
# creating a dictionary containing potential values of alpha
alpha_values = {'alpha':[0.0001,0.001, 0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.08, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 20, 50, 100]}
# Passing in a Ridge estimator, potential alpha values, scoring method and cross validation parameters to the GridSearchCV
ridge= GridSearchCV(Ridge(), alpha_values, cv=10 )
# Fitting the model to the data and extracting best value of alpha
print('The best value of alpha is:',ridge.fit(X_train, y_train).best_params_)
```

It took alpha as 0.0001 as give the same result. The same case for Lasso as well

How can I improve these models

Answer (score 0):

You can create some features and train new models on those features.
Also, try to do some hyperparameter tuning of the ridge and lasso regressors and maybe that can improve the performance.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Is removing some input variable is good approch